"No module named PyQt5.sip" error when using PyQGIS in standalone script
I tried to run Python code from PyQGIS Developer Cookbook | Using PyQGIS in standalone scripts
on Windows 10, but I got an error:

I installed PyQt5 and PyQt5-sip, and set all paths but the error remained.
The folder Python310\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5 contains sip.pyi and sip.cp310-win_amd64.pyd files, but it's probably not enough.
What could be the problem and how can I get a sip package?

You don't need to do a separate install of PyQt5 and PyQt5-sip, that's included with QGIS. Have you set PYTHONPATH and PATH environment variables as per 1.4.3 section of the doc you linked to?
